# how to upgrade iphone 3gs ios 4 to ios 6 directly?

Tags: upgrade, ios, iphone

Is it possible to upgrade directly to iOS 6 while from iOS 4? I'm just new with apple gadgets. iTunes only shows ios 4.2. Does it require me to upgrade one step at a time? It took a lot of time if it does. ;(

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you're stuck on iOS 4. iOS 6 is no longer being signed by Apple (since iOS 7 is the current version), so you can't install it. But you also can't install iOS 7 since it doesn't support the iPhone 3GS.

Comment: @daGUY a 3GS cannot go to iOS7 and the latest version is iOS 6.1.6, a upgrade should be possible.

Comment: @user71568 When did you upgrade your iTunes the last time? Please try upgrading it to 4.2 first, it actually should install iOS6 since Apple does not sign iOS 4 (or 5) anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to go in the order of the updates available. Sometimes this makes more sense for Apple to do instead of merging all of the updates into one, at least for smaller updates. After you update to 4.2, if your device is compatible with any higher versions, it should recommend the latest version of it.

Comment: There's always only one version available, which is the latest. Apple does not sign "old" versions.